# Why is CoInitialize an undeclared identifier?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, initialization

I use `UniDac` component to connect to `PostgreSQL`. My `Query` is running in a separate thread. Now when I use `CoInitialize` in the thread, I receive this compiler error:

> - [DCC Error] QryThread.pas(41): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'CoInitialize'

Why?

Comment: please edit your post to include the code segment that calls `CoInitialize`

Comment: You need to include the unit which contains `CoInitialize`.

Comment: @DR, You should have posted it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @vcldeveloper: I would have, but I wasn't sure about the correct unit.

Comment: A better name for this question would be "what does undeclared identifier error mean".   As it stands this question is so specific as to be really not-very-useful to anybody.

Comment: It was useful to me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because `ActiveX` is missing in the uses list.